# Cronjob on bitnami google server not working

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, server, cron

I have been trying without success to run a cronjob that backs up my database. I keep getting a "30: No such file or directory" when a run the crontab using the following codes on the command line:

```
crontab 30 19 *** cd /home/bitnami/db_backup /home/bitnami/db_backup/db_backup.sh
```

But when I run the script by running the below script, It works perfectly.

```
sh /home/bitnami/db_backup/db_backup.sh
```

I really do not know what I am missing and I'd appreciate any help in helping me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `crontab -e` and add `* * * * * bash /home/saketh/Documents/workspace/sample.sh` 
(change the frequency of this job & path accordingly i.e `30 19 * * *`; I recommend to use `* * * * * bash <absolute path to .sh file>` for testing purposes, if the job is small enough) at the end of the file.

I would suggest you to mention `absolute path` i.e the path starting from the `root (/)` till the end (`/xx/xx/xx/...../sample.sh`) instead of `cd /xxx/xxx` and `bash /continuation/yyy`

Comment: Thanks @Saketh Katari, I didn't use the bash command before the directory. You just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
~#crontab -e
```

in crontab add:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 19 * * * /home/bitnami/db_backup/db_backup.sh
```

- use space between '*'